# My table headers disappear with visualforce datatable

Tags: apex, visualforce

I am trying to creating some table headers for my table in my visualforce page, but when loaded on the internet only the table body is shown.

**Apex:**

```
<apex:page showHeader="false" title="My Orders" standardController="Service_Order__c" recordSetVar="orders">
  <apex:composition template="{!$Site.Template}">
    <apex:define name="body">  

    <h2>My Orders</h2>
    <p>Orders will go here</p>

    <apex:dataTable value="{!orders}" var="so" width="100%">

        <table>
            <thead>
                <tr>
                    <th>ID</th>
                    <th>Name</th>
                    <th></th>
                </tr>
            </thead>
            <tbody>
                <tr>
                    <td>
                        <apex:column >
                            <apex:outputText value="{!so.Id}"/>
                        </apex:column>
                    </td>
                    <td>
                        <apex:column >
                            <apex:outputText value="{!so.Name}"/>
                        </apex:column>
                    </td>
                    <td>
                        <apex:column >
                            <apex:outputLink styleClass="" value="/{!so.id}">VIEW</apex:outputLink>
                        </apex:column>
                    </td>
                </tr>
            </tbody>
        </table>

    </apex:dataTable> 

    </apex:define>
  </apex:composition>
</apex:page>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Theres a few things wrong, such as the [apex:column](http://www.salesforce.com/us/developer/docs/pages/Content/pages_compref_column.htm) should be a child of [apex:dataTable](http://www.salesforce.com/us/developer/docs/pages/Content/pages_compref_dataTable.htm)

If you are trying to create your table in HTML then you can try using a [apex:repeat](https://www.salesforce.com/us/developer/docs/pages/Content/pages_compref_repeat.htm) tag to repeat over each of the orders.

```
<table>
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th>ID</th>
            <th>Name</th>
            <th></th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
        <apex:repeat var="so" value="{!orders}">
            <tr>
                <td>
                    <apex:outputText value="{!so.Id}"/>
                </td>
                <td>
                     <apex:outputText value="{!so.Name}"/>
                </td>
                <td>
                    <apex:outputLink styleClass="" value="/{!so.id}">VIEW</apex:outputLink>
                </td>
            </tr>
         </apex:repeat>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

but if you really want to use [apex:dataTable](http://www.salesforce.com/us/developer/docs/pages/Content/pages_compref_dataTable.htm) then the example below should work:

```
<apex:dataTable value="{!orders}" var="so">
    <apex:column>
        <apex:facet name="header">Id</apex:facet>
        <apex:outputText value="{!so.Id}"/>
    </apex:column>
    <apex:column>
        <apex:facet name="header">Name</apex:facet>
        <apex:outputText value="{!so.Name}"/>
    </apex:column>
    <apex:column>
        <apex:facet name="header"></apex:facet>
        <apex:outputLink styleClass="" value="/{!so.id}">VIEW</apex:outputLink>
    </apex:column>
</apex:dataTable>
```

Answer (score 2):

Why don't you use the example given in the doc :

```
   <apex:dataTable value="{!orders}" var="so" width="100%">
       <apex:column >
           <apex:facet name="header">ID</apex:facet>
           <apex:outputText value="{!so.Id}"/>
       </apex:column>

       <apex:column >
           <apex:facet name="header">Name</apex:facet>
           <apex:outputText value="{!so.Name}"/>
       </apex:column>

       <apex:column >
           <apex:outputLink styleClass="" value="/{!so.id}">VIEW</apex:outputLink>
       </apex:column>
</apex:dataTable>
```

See : http://www.salesforce.com/us/developer/docs/pages/Content/pages_compref_dataTable.htm